# In-Universe explanation why the founder seem so crude

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, shape-shifter

In Star Trek - Deep Space 9, it is explained that Odo has some troubles (for lack of a better word) with shapeshifting. This results in him to look crude, his features unfinished (e.g. his ears are simple surfaces instead of the wobbles we have:

[image: Odo]

In the series, it is also mentioned that the Founders are way more skilled in the art of shapeshifting. This to the level of being able to [mimic Martok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Martok_(Changeling)). Nontheless, throughout the series, the female changling decided to have the same crude features as Odo has when not mimicing somebody.

[image: Female Changling]

I assume this has been done in order to clearly identify her as a changeling to the viewers. However, I cannot think of an in-universe explanation to why she would decide to have the same crude features as Odo has, given her skills enable her to look however she wants. So, what in-universe reason was there for her to appear in this way?

Comment: "This results in him to look crude, his features unfinished" — typical solid, so racist. "I cannot think of an in-universe explanation to why she would decide to have the same crude features as Odo" — the Founders want Odo to return to them. How better to win his trust than mimic his appearance?

Comment: Nothing to back this up, so this is a comment rather than an answer: She mimicks him to make him feel more comfortable.

Comment: If she doesn't look like Odo, how will everyone know she's a shapeshifter?

Comment: @Philipp: I thought she actually said that at some point.